# How to make SWRevealViewController menu disappear when users tap on the view-controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have View controller with embedded SWRevealViewController I've added code below to disable any interaction while the menu on use.

The viewcontroller is embeded with tableview.

**How to make menu disappears when users tap on the view-controller as the slack app "When the menu is on use and you tap on the chat the menu disappears"**

```
  class Feed: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }

    fetchMessages()
}





func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, didMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
    {
        if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: when the sw_rear menu is on I can't get back to viewcontroller "sw_front" even if the the tap it going back only if press menu button or I picked from the menu

Comment: so I want the user to tap on the viewcontroller to get back

Comment: calculate the window position >0 , add your pan gesture here in delegate methods

Comment: _frontViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rightViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;
    _rearViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
    _rearViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f;

Comment: no no not like that man, wait I submit the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//set the delegate in your view controller class

```
class FeedVC: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate 


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  self.revealViewController().delegate = self
    var swl=self.revealViewController()


    if swl != nil
    {
        swl.panGestureRecognizer()
        swl.tapGestureRecognizer()
    }
}
```

// create the left bar button action

```
@IBAction func but_back(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate=self
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target=self.revealViewController()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action=Selector("revealToggle:")
    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(sender)

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

//set the delegate method for SWLReval

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=true
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        revealController.panGestureRecognizer().enabled=false
    }



}
```

the updated code is available in this link , download the project in [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/i0cepy)

Comment: can you send your project to my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: @marrioa -- where is your swlrevalviewcontoller on storyboard, it is missing man

Comment: it is there ! It is the initial VC.

Comment: what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @marrioa - the problem is over , wait I upload the project

Comment: problem is you forget to implement the tap gesture